# NullPointerException with Primefaces' draggable DataTable and CommandButton

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a very basic page containing a DataTable and a CommandButton:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
  <p:dataTable id="npeTestTable"
           var="_element" value="#{testBB.listOfElements}"
           draggableColumns="true" >
    <p:column headerText="Column one">
      <h:outputText value="#{_element}" />
    </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>

  <h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Click me" />
  </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The method `testBB.getListOfElements()` just returns a collection of `Integer`-values.
The essential thing is, that the DataTable has the attribute `draggableColumns="true"` set. If I click the CommandButton, I get the following `NullPointerException`:

```
09:59:04,018 SCHWERWIEGEND [org.primefaces.extensions.component.ajaxerrorhandler.AjaxExceptionHandler] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-6) null: javax.faces.FacesException
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:86) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.16.Final.jar:2013-09-23 14:44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:115) [omnifaces-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75) [omnifaces-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [shiro-web-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [shiro-web-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383) [shiro-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.DraggableColumnsFeature.decode(DraggableColumnsFeature.java:35) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:60) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:787) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:232) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:933) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    ... 34 more
```

The `DraggableColumnsFeature` want's to get the `columnOrder` of the request-parameter, but it isn't in. The call to `split` raises the exception.

For me this seems to be a Primefaces-bug. Since the example looks very basic, I cannot believe that this issue has not been detected so far. So I'm not sure if I missed an important thing or concept (which is basically the question I wanted to ask).

I'm running Primefaces 4.0, Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1, JBoss 7.1.1.

Comment: Put your `<p:dataTable>` inside the `<h:form>`. Others seem to have the [similiar](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4623) [problems](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14568&sid=220f1d9168822dc9b80b8707b4451d89) with older PrimeFaces versions. Unfortunately it is not mentioned in the manual, that the `p:dataTable` should apparently be included in a form.

Comment: Thank you Martin. Indeed, your suggestion works and there is no `NullPointerException` any more. I'm not sure if it is always practicable to put the tables into the form. Anyways - it would be nice to get some hint like the well-known "...must be inside a form element"

Comment: @MartinHöller Martin. Please make an answer from your comment. I will be glad to up vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `<p:dataTable>` inside a `<h:form>`.

```
<html>
  ...
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
      <p:dataTable id="npeTestTable"
                   var="_element" value="#{testBB.listOfElements}"
                   draggableColumns="true" >
        ...
      </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

Others seem to have [similiar](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4623) [problems](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14568) with older PrimeFaces versions. Unfortunately it is not mentioned in the manual, that a dataTable should apparently be included in a form.